# Does "Paradise lies beneath your mother feet" imply the value of a mother is greater than the value of heaven?

Tags: hadith, jannah

There is a hadith which says "Paradise lies beneath your mothers feet".

Does this mean that the value of a mother is greater than the value of heaven? So a mother will always be more valuable then paradise?

I'm asking this because usually when something is beneath someone's feet, it's a sign of disrespect, or of lesser value, like its smaller and less valuable.

Comment: See the answers [here](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35640/paradise-lies-beneath-your-mothers-feet-hadith-shirk).

Comment: I've read that post a several times now but I can't really see the answer in it. Sorry am I missing something?

Comment: The meaning of the hadith is "honoring your mother is a great deed worthy of high reward". "Beneath her feet" indicates how subservient the child should be to the mother, because they will find paradise by being beneath her feet.

Comment: I think my answer on this question http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/35640/paradise-lies-beneath-your-mothers-feet-hadith-shirk should solve the issue!

Answer (score 2):

that is a metaphorical statement, It means the best way through which Paradise can be achieved is by obeying and honoring your mother.

Answer (score 0):

of course this only means that you should take care of your mother, it has nothing to do with paradise value comparing or such, the hadith you mentioned reminds me of this one.

> A man came to the Prophet and said, ‘O Messenger of God! Who among
>   the people is the most worthy of my good companionship? The Prophet
>   said: Your mother. The man said, ‘Then who?' The Prophet said: Then
>   your mother. The man further asked, ‘Then who?' The Prophet said: Then
>   your mother. The man asked again, ‘Then who?' The Prophet said: Then
>   your father. (Bukhari, Muslim).

you can say it means that a mother takes the golden medal, the silver medal, and the bronze medal, and a father is left with consoling prizes.